# Is there a function satisfying the following equation: $f(\sin x)+f(\cos x) = \frac{\tan x}{2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Define a function $f(x)$ such that:

$$f(\sin x)+f(\cos x)=\frac{\tan x}2$$

What is $f(x)?$

My attempt: I hypothesized the denominator of the function to be like of the form $x+(1-x^2)^{1/2}$

Comment: @Benjamin Moss: Thanks for editing

Comment: Maybe It would be more correct to create a new OP. Now what of my answer. I think it's not a good way to change questions in this manner.

Comment: @gimusi i already told you my attempt, you should have given other suggested solve. It is defined for 0 to pi/2

Comment: Since some users are unhappy about their answers being invalidated by the edit, I removed it. Please ask a new question referencing this one for context.

Comment: On $(0,\pi/2)$, my answer still applies.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art Thanks for all your efforts

Comment: @quid okay i got it

Answer (score 28, accepted):

More general than [gimusi's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2554128), notice that

$$\sin(x)=\cos(\pi/2-x)\\\cos(x)=\sin(\pi/2-x)$$

And so

$$f(\sin(x))+f(\cos(x))=f(\sin(\pi/2-x))+f(\cos(\pi/2-x))$$

But

$$\tan(x)\ne\tan(\pi/2-x)$$

Comment: nice generalization!

Comment: So all we need to ensure is that the domain $D$ of $f$ is small enough never to contain both $x$ and $y$ when $x^2+y^2=1$ (except that $D$ may contain $\sqrt 2/2$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen so you are proposing that whenever $f(\sin(x))$ exists, then $f(\cos(x))$ doesn't exist, and vice versa? I'm not sure of any reasonable interpretation of the question if that is he case you seek.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Yes exactly what i want is the one you said

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art I still think it works for extremely infinitesimally small values

Comment: @ChenGuo I still do not understand what you and Hagen want. If you make the domain of $f$ never include both values so that the contradiction in my answer doesn't occur, then the functional equation you've provided won't make any sense....

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art I will show you if i get it. I am working, please, requesting you to wait

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art follow my last answer...see it satisfies for x=pi/4. So a function can obviously be defined

Comment: @ChenGuo My answer does not suggest it can't work for $x=\pi/4$. In fact, my answer suggests that $f$ is defined only if $\sin(x)=\cos(x)$.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art Yes it does but there must be some function for some small limiting values

Comment: I think f can be defined only with a single value domain. `{d}` where `d = sqrt(2)/2` or `d = -sqrt(2)/2` and `f(d) = 1/4`

Comment: @ypercube Thats correct

Comment: It would be interesting to check if there are other solutions, in the domain of R (or C) outside of `[-1,1]` (and `x` in C)

Comment: @ypercube yes but do you have time to do so? If so then please do

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yes, we will have $f(t)=1/4$ for any $t=\sin(x)=\cos(x)$ for complex $x$, but that's about it.

Answer (score 21):

It is **not possible**, infact:

> for $x=0: f(0)+f(1)=0$
>
> for $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$: $f(1)+f(0)$ = **RHS is not defined**

Comment: Still i think there must be some way

Comment: Well, what if we don’t input values of x, and try with help of algebraic/trigonometric identities? Is there no way to do this?

Comment: @ John Watson Okay editing, but i want to apply algebra, instead of inputting values of x

Comment: @ChenGuo This answer shows that there is no solution: but even in general, "there must be some way" is not correct. For example, consider the equation $x = \sin x$. There is no way, with just algebraic or trigonometric steps, to solve for $x$. It has been proved to be impossible. The only thing we can do is approximate a numerical solution.

Comment: @Ovi We know limit as x tend to 0 sin(x)/x = 1. So x is very small. And this has a proof.

Comment: @Ovi maybe it requires limit

Comment: @ChenGuo I don't see how a limit can help when commutativity is broken. For this to work, you'd have to redefine the $+$ operation, and then you might as make up whatever you want.

Comment: @muru + or - results the same in case of infinitesimal small quantity

Comment: @ChenGuo no they don't. But do tell us what $\sin(x+\epsilon)$ is supposed to be for real $x$ and infinitesimal $\epsilon$?

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art yes why not?

Comment: @ChenGuo That doesn't answer the question of what you mean by infinitesimals and all that here.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art I already accepted your answer. Still i am not satisfied.

Comment: @ChenGuo Then don't accept it until you are satisfied.

Comment: You could also take in consideration the idea to continue your discussion on the chat! Thanks!

Comment: the OP`s statement does not necessary precised that fonction must be defined in spécifique point

Comment: @Guy Fsone Ok but a function can't give 2 different results with the same entries. Here we have: f(0)+f(1)=0 AND f(1)+f(0)=N.D.!

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art How can i ignore a solution from you? I am nothing in front of you. You are so good in calculus. So i am bound to accept your answer Sir

Comment: @gimusi I still think there must be a way out....

Comment: @ChenGuo ok let me know in case you'll find it!

Comment: @gimusi sure i will

Comment: +1) @gimusi God! How did you think?

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks I immediately saw it, despite Chen Guo never admited my the correctness point but he has considered correct the "generalization" by Simply Beautiful Art! The lesson is: simply answer often don't like so much to many mathematicians.

Comment: Hello! friend, I know this is not appropriate place to talk but I couldn't help. I had to thank you. @user